# Evaluate if list is empty JSTL

Tags: java, jsp, jstl

I've been trying to evaluate if this array list is empty or not but none of these have even compiled:

```
<c:if test="${myObject.featuresList.size == 0 }">                   
<c:if test="${myObject.featuresList.length == 0 }">                 
<c:if test="${myObject.featuresList.size() == 0 }">                 
<c:if test="${myObject.featuresList.length() == 0 }">                   
<c:if test="${myObject.featuresList.empty}">                    
<c:if test="${myObject.featuresList.empty()}">                  
<c:if test="${myObject.featuresList.isEmpty}">
```

How can I evaluate if an ArrayList is empty?

Answer (score 256, accepted):

[`empty`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13712/reference.htm#sthref163) is an *operator*:

> The `empty` operator is a *prefix* operation that can be used to determine
>   whether a value is null or empty.

```
<c:if test="${empty myObject.featuresList}">
```

Comment: Although it is documented that the empty operator doesn't play well with Set implementation of Collections in JSTL prior to v2.0

Answer (score 68):

There's also the function tags, a bit more flexible:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
<c:if test="${fn:length(list) > 0}">
```

And [here's](http://java.sun.com/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/index.html) the tag documentation.